# Excel macro the code is not working

Tags: excel, vba

this code inexcel macro doesn't work :

```
Sheets("2").Select
Range("A1:C7").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sayfa1").Select
Range("D6:F12").Select
```

What is the problem?

I need your help.

Note : I don't have a good English. Pardon me. I hope you understand.

Comment: (1) Do you have a sheet with a name of `"2"`?  (2) Do you have a sheet with a name of `"Sayfa1"`?  (3) If the answers to the first two questions are both "yes", please tell us more about what you mean when you say it "doesn't work".  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to copy data from sheet "2" to sheet "Sayfa1". Your code then should look like:

```
Sheets("2").Select
Range("A1:C7").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sayfa1").Select
Range("D6:F12").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Easiest way to do this is via:

```
Sheets("Sayfa1").Range("D6:F12").Value = Sheets("2").Range("A1:C7").Value
```

This avoids using (slow) `.Copy or .Select`

If you want to copy all, including formats, its better to use this:

```
Sheets("2").Range("A1:C7").Copy
Sheets("Sayfa1").Range("D6:F12").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```